# Unable to add Outlook 2016 web add-in to windows and Mac clients

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-2016

I am trying to create a very simple web outlook add-ins (Using JavaScript + HTML5 + CSS).  This is the same add-in described in the tutorial.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/quick-start?tabs=visual-studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRw6r.png)

I am able to create the add-in and add it to Outlook 2016 web client.  When I open the outlook web client and use the add-in, it works perfectly.

Now I am trying to add same add-in to Outlook 2016 client installed on Windows and MAC. On both the machines when I search and add the add-in (with add from file option), it gets added successfully. I get the “installed successfully “message.  I even see it under “my add-ins” option.  But it does not show up in the toolbar. When I again open the store and check the “my add-in” list, the add-in is disappeared form the list.  This means it never got installed correctly.

Since I am new to this, I am not able to determine the reason or debug the issue.  Is there any change I need to do to manifest file? Currently I am using the same manifest file for web client, windows and mac based client.  Also how do I debug this?

Update:

Here is the manifest file I am using for registering add-in in web client. I am using the same file for windows and mac clients. Is the manifest file different?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
          xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0"
          xsi:type="MailApp">

  <!-- Begin Basic Settings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided. -->

  <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->
  <Id>771983a0-73ed-45a0-90d9-0fd546592d94</Id>

  <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Amey Kale</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="My Office Add-in" />
  <Description DefaultValue="My First Outlook Add-in"/>

  <!-- Icon for your add-in. Used on installation screens and the add-ins dialog. -->
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost/OWA/" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://dev.sgsuite.com/OWA/assets/hi-res-icon.png"/>

  <!--If you plan to submit this add-in to the Office Store, uncomment the SupportUrl element below-->
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://dev.sgsuite.com/OWA/assets/hi-res-icon.png" />

  <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain1</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain2</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain3</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <!--End Basic Settings. -->

  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://dev.sgsuite.com/OWA/index.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">

        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
          <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />

          <!-- Message Read -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                    <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
          <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>

    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://dev.sgsuite.com/OWA/assets/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://dev.sgsuite.com/OWA/assets/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://dev.sgsuite.com/OWA/assets/icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="https://dev.sgsuite.com/OWA/function-file/function-file.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://dev.sgsuite.com/OWA/index.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="My Add-in Group"/>
        <bt:String id="customTabLabel"  DefaultValue="My Add-in Tab"/>
        <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Display all properties"/>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Get all properties"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties. This is an example of a button that opens a task pane."/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

When registering the add-in from desktop client, I am getting following certificate error:
[image]

But when I register it from web client it does not give me this error, even though the web server is same.

Comment: Can you share the manifest that you are using?

Comment: @ Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT, I have updated the question with manifest file.

Comment: Could you try View Certificate and add it? and then say yes to proceed and see if the add-in works? It could be that SSL certificates do not have the right data?